# How to add an abstract method in Java

Tags: java, java-7

Ok. I am stuck on this part of my assignment. I need to add an abstract method named getDisplayText to the Product Class(Code given below for it). Please show me where to put it and how. that would be very kind of you. Also, this method should accept no parameters, and it should return a string object. Then compile this class.(Sorry my english is bad...-what does this thing means?! save the file?!)

Here is the code:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public abstract class Product {
private String code;
private String description;
private double price;
public static int count = 0;

public Product() {
    code = "";
    description = "";
    price = 0;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getFormattedPrice() {
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    return currency.format(price);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Code:        " + code + "\n" + "Description: " + description + "\n" + "Price:       "
            + this.getFormattedPrice() + "\n";
}

public static int getCount() {
    return count;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Abstract methods are indicated by two things:

1. The `abstract` modifier
2. No method body.

So

```
public abstract String getDisplayText();
```

should be it, I guess.

Comment: where should i put this?! just below public abstract class Product??

Comment: Wherever you feel it fits well. Order of members in a class has no relevance other than what you're comfortable with reading.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this to your class:

```
public abstract String getDisplayText();
```

Comment: where should i put this?! just below public abstract class Product??

Comment: Anywhere within your class. The position of the method within the class isn't important.

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this.

```
abstract String getDisplayText();
```

Comment: where exactly should I put this in the above code?! I am getting error in the code when i insert it

Answer (score 0):

For abstract class, methods may be abstract or not. So we need to specify abstract keywork to indicate it.

In abstract class :

```
abstract String getDisplayText();
```

And if you are adding in interface:

```
String getDisplayText();
```

Becayuse of java doc:

> All of the methods in an interface (see the Interfaces section) are
>   implicitly abstract, so the abstract modifier is not used with
>   interface methods